# can i setup a onItemClickListener in android system 's sms inbox to start a custom activity？

Tags: android, sms

in my acticity ,i open the android system's sms inbox with this code:

---

`Intent mIntent = new Intent();
            mIntent.setClassName("com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.ui.ConversationList");
            startActivity(mIntent);`

how can i set a onItemClickLietener to start my custom activity ?

Comment: my English is so pool. is there anyone catch my meaning? help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i open the android system's sms inbox with this code

Note that many Android users do not use this app, and I would not be surprised if many Android devices do not have this activity.

> how can i set a onItemClickLietener to start my custom activity ?

You can't. You are welcome to write your own SMS client app, though.